# Rescaling parent element without affecting child elements

Tags: geometry, vectors

Given the following two dimensional plane within the boundaries of `0.0` and `1.0` on both axis where the origin of coordinates begins at the top-left (0, 0), a 2D rectangle exists within the full area of the plane. This rectangle has a child rectangle *(blue)*, the child rectangle's position and size is scaled to the width and height of the parent such that when the parent is resized, the child is rescaled with it.

[image]

[image]

I want to avoid this behaviour and retain the original position and size of the child rectangle after the parent is rescaled.

For instance, given the following adjustments to size of the parent rectangle:

- **SizeX:** `1.0 --> 0.8`
- **SizeY:** `1.0 --> 0.8`

The total adjustment here is `-0.2` to both the width and height, I have tried simply taking this value and adding it to the child element to resize it back to its original width and height however this doesn't result in the intended behaviour. The correct size and positioning of the blue rectangle after the parent has rescaled should be:

[image]

What is the correct formula to adjust the scale of the child element after the parent has been resized?

Comment: You need to multiply the width and length of the child rectangle by the reciprocal of the scale factor of the parent rectangle.  That's all you need to do.

Comment: Using your example, you scaled the parent by $0.8$, so you have to scale the child by $1/0.8 = 1.25 $ in order for it to keep its original size.   That is, the child is scaled by the process inherent in your software by $0.8$, so you correct that by scaling it alone by $1.25$.